# Change styles of third party components in react native

Tags: react-native

Very often I'm seeing that third party react native components don't provide granular access to changing their styles. On web we can target and style different parts based on their CSS classes. If a react native component does not provide enough props for changing styles, how to go about changing its styles?

Comment: a very practical idea that me personally did a lot of time is to go to node_modules/third_party folder and modify files by hand. beside being practical it is also a very flexible idea

Comment: That means you have to maintain a fork of the component?

Comment: notice that, you can change node_module_third_party folder, but if you remove your node_module folder all changes back to original state.

Comment: @Moein is right this is a lazy solution. you own idea of keeping a fork is much cleaner.

Comment: i am agree, fork is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to me to read the third party lib code on github and then write a component that do the same thing but with my styles, Generally speaking it's not much complex depending on the library of course, for small libs it works very well.

It's only worth when the lib doesn't provide a way of overriding styles as you have pointed.

You also can see the style implementation of lib's main component and override it's styles, using JSS or styled-components lib.